# Async function not working using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have a function using prototype for my objects but now in need of making an asynchronous call for setting some inputs the problem is that i am getting  `$$(...).asyncEach is not a function` here is my code snippet

```
Customers.prototype.AddDatePickers = function()
{
    $j.fn.asyncEach = function(callback){
       var i = 0;
       var elements = this;
       var timer = setInterval(function () {
           callback.call(elements[i], elements[i]);
           if(++i >= elements.length) clearInterval(timer);
       }, 0);
    }

    $$('.dateInputs').asyncEach(function (input) {
       $(this).kendoDatePicker();
    });
}
```

The reason why I have to do this is because there are lots of inputs with date pickers that need to get created so the unresponsive script message shows. I am trying to avoid that and this was given as an answer, my problem is I think (i am new to jquery) is that it is in a prototype function?, usually when I need to use `$` i have to use `$j` in my prototype functions so that there is no conflict. But with this set up I am not really sure how to make it work.

Comment: Note you are calling `asyncEach` (no 'h')

Comment: thats not the issue, its a copy paste typo sorry - i fixed the typo thanks

Comment: Your code results in a syntax error, as you're missing a `)`.

Comment: `$$('.dateInputs')` should be `$j('.dateInputs')`

Comment: $$ is a selector by css class no?

Comment: Nope. that's prototype i believe. What you want is `$j` there.

Comment: so dateInputs is a css class, would it still be valid?

Comment: Yes, jquery can select elements by css class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose you described, it could be a lot simpler. The following should do.

```
$('.dateInputs').each(function() {
    var element = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(element).kendoDatePicker();
    }, 0);
});
```

**Note:** I'm using the standard jquery notation, you can modify it your no-conflict version.

Also, your version has a bug in it that calls the `callback` at least once even if the elements were empty.